# Making a JPanel disappear on Jbutton click

Tags: java, user-interface

I have a problem with two JPanels. Both are represented by a green rectangle, one bigger than the other. I have been trying to swap from one panel to the other, meaning, when you click the button one replaces the other in the frame. However I cannot find a solution for the second to appear. The most I got is to make the first hide. How should I focus it? I am out of ideas.

```
public class GrowAndShrinkSquareGUI {
    JFrame frame;
    SquareDrawPanel greenPanel;

    public class SquareDrawPanel extends JPanel {
        int locationX;
        int locationY;
        int width;
        int height;

        SquareDrawPanel(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
            locationX = x;
            locationY = y;
            width = w;
            height = h;
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.fillRect(locationX, locationY, width, height);
        }
    }

    public class growAndShrinkListener implements ActionListener {
        JButton button;
        public growAndShrinkListener() {
            JButton button = new JButton("Click me to grow the Square");
            frame.add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            button.addActionListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.print("clicked");        
            greenPanel.setVisible(false);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GrowAndShrinkSquareGUI test = new GrowAndShrinkSquareGUI();
        test.go();
    }

    public void go() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        drawPanel(greenPanel);

        growAndShrinkListener button = new growAndShrinkListener();
        //addButton(CreateJButton());
    }

    private JPanel createRectPanel(int x, int y) {
        greenPanel = new SquareDrawPanel(x, y, 100, 100);
        return greenPanel;
    }

    private void drawPanel(JPanel panel) {
        panel = createRectPanel(setLocationX(), setLocationY());
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER); // DoesNot run properly
    }

    private int setLocationX() {
        int centeredX = frame.getWidth() / 2 - 50;
        return centeredX;
    }

    private int setLocationY() {
        int centeredY = frame.getHeight() / 2 - 75;
        return centeredY;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at using a `CardPanel`?

Comment: Can you post a little bit more of your code? At the moment, your code includes one button and one panel but your question references two panels.

Comment: I have tried creating a new Panel, with other paremeters, but when I try to implement it in the button listener, well, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

For this specific task, you should use a [`CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), which enables you to quickly switch between "cards". Cards are essentially `JComponent`s associated with a name:

```
public class GrowAndShrinkSquareGUI {
    CardLayout layout;
    JPanel cardPanel; // Holds the cards

    public class SquareDrawPanel extends JPanel {
        int locationX;
        int locationY;
        int width;
        int height;

        SquareDrawPanel(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
            locationX = x;
            locationY = y;
            width = w;
            height = h;
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.fillRect(locationX, locationY, width, height);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GrowAndShrinkSquareGUI test = new GrowAndShrinkSquareGUI();
        test.go();
    }

    public void go() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Set up CardLayout
        layout = new CardLayout();

        // Set up the first panel
        JPanel firstPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JButton switchButton = new JButton("Switch to green panel!");
        switchButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                layout.show(cardPanel, "green");
            }
        }
        firstPanel.add(switchButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        layout.add(firstPanel, "first");

        // Set up the second panel
        JPanel secondPanel = new SquareDrawPanel(5, 5, 50, 50);
        layout.add(secondPanel, "green");

        // Set up the main panel
        cardPanel = new JPanel(layout);
        frame.add(cardPanel);
    }

    private int setLocationX() {
        int centeredX = frame.getWidth() / 2 - 50;
        return centeredX;
    }

    private int setLocationY() {
        int centeredY = frame.getHeight() / 2 - 75;
        return centeredY;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am reading and learning through your code, will post results when I got something. Many thanks!